# How to end a region with the same text from the beginning c#

Tags: c#, tabs, editor, region

Just like prop or propfull and then tabs ... I saw once the same thing with regions.... #region(tab) and the code editor will generate the space to write the name of the region and it will generate the endregion also. But once I saw that someone did a tab after region and the text that we write for the region is copied at the end of the region automatically. Does anyone know if this is configuration, shortcut or addin instead of copy and paste the text.

```
#region **Private members**

#endregion **Private members**
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you're referring to is Code Snippets. See [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z41h7fat.aspx). They're pretty useful. You can edit them, The Code snippets Manager in `Tools` -> `Code Snippets Manager`  will show you the directory.
This is specifically in Visual Studio. Other editors also have similar features

Comment: Thanks. I edited the snippet to add $name$ in #endregion and it works!!